# How to use dataframe of urls as your source for the start_urls in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scraper that works just fine using a csv file for the start urls. I have 2 other scripts that retrive the target names, then find the api UUIDs so I can then scrape all the urls I gathered in a pandas dataframe. As of now I am outputing my urls to csv file from the dataframe that cleans my urls; then importing that csv file in to my scrapy script to go out and fetch my data followed by another output csv file.

I want to be able to just wire up the dataframe that already has the URLs in it? Instead of creating a csv and re-reading it back in to my script.

**My dataFrame**

```
  Data_List  = [list of URLS]

df_api_data = pd.DataFrame(Data_List)
api_file_name = 'data_apis_' + tm + '.csv'
path = r'1_wiki_apis/'
df_api_data.to_csv(path + api_file_name, header=None, index=False)
```

**Scrapy Script**

```
    lass DataCrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'data_crawler'
# Import clean list of api urls from csv
filepath = 'api_urls/api_urls_' + tm + '.csv'
custom_settings = {
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 32,
    'FEEDS': {'final_data/raw_data_' + tm + '.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},
# Open csv file and iterate through each row
with open(filepath) as file:
    start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]
    POI_URLS = start_urls
# Callback to handle query list
def start_request(self):
    request = Request(url=self.start_urls, callback=self.parse)
# yield request and parse scraped data
def parse(self, response):
    # Xpath variables
    POI_DOD = response.xpath(get_dod).get()
    POI_GENDER = response.xpath(get_gender).get()
    # Get the wikidata response
    yield {
        'DISPLAY_CODE': '(NULL)',
        '_DOD': _DOD,
        '_GENDER': _GENDER,

        # NEW DATA COLUMNS
        '_INDUSTRY': _INDUSTRY,
        '_EDUCATION': _EDUCATION,
        '_EXCERPT': _EXCERPT,
    }
# pass


# Execute script to crawl Wiki database and get POI Data
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(DataCrawlerSpider)
process.start()
```

How can I use my `df_api_data`  dataframe full apis in the `start_urls[]` ?

Comment: Maybe you should accept answers

Answer (score 0):

Just take you Data_List and plug that directly into your `start_requests` method in your spider and yield a request for each item in the list.

If you must use the dataframe then all you need to do is to extract a the column with the urls into a series and call `series.to_list()` and do the same thing.

```
from scrapy import Request
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

Data_List  = [list of URLS]

# or with a dataframe:
Data_List = dataframe["column with the urls"].to_list()


class DataCrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'data_crawler'

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 32,
        'FEEDS': {'final_data/raw_data_' + tm + '.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},

    def start_request(self):
        for url in Data_List:
            yield Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        POI_DOD = response.xpath(get_dod).get()
        POI_GENDER = response.xpath(get_gender).get()
        yield {
            'DISPLAY_CODE': '(NULL)',
            '_DOD': _DOD,
            '_GENDER': _GENDER,
            '_INDUSTRY': _INDUSTRY,
            '_EDUCATION': _EDUCATION,
            '_EXCERPT': _EXCERPT,
        }

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(DataCrawlerSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Yeah I have to use the dataframe because I am cleaning my  list of urls and dropping certain ones I don't need then piping that to scrapy to crawl

Comment: Okay...  so did the solution work for you then?